# How to check if a Git Repo has uncommitted changes using Python

Tags: python, git

I'm pretty new to git, but I'm trying to use python to check if a git repository has any uncommitted changes. I seem to get the same error no matter what command I try to run using python. Here's my code:

```
from git import *
repo = Repo("path\to\my\repo")
lastCommit = repo.head.commit.committed_date
uncommitted = repo.is_dirty()
```

Everything works as expected until I run the last line which is when I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
    raise GitCommandNotFound: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried this with other commands too and I get the same error. For example, `repo.index.diff(repo.head.commit)`. I've also tried running `repo.index.diff(None)` and `repo.index.diff('HEAD')` which give the same error. What I really want is to essentially run `$ git status` for the repository I've named `repo`. I'm using Python 2.7.9 and gitpython 1.0.1 on Windows 7.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example (which is only for illustration purposes), your `"path\to\my\repo"` would be understood as `'path\to\\my\repo'`. Use a double backslash between the components of your path (`"path\\to\\my\\repo"`). `\t` is understood as a tab, and `\r` is understood as a carriage return. Alternatively, you can put a `r` in front of your path like so: `r"path\to\my\repo"`

Comment: These "[string lterals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)" are known as raw strings, but remember this is just a different way to represent strings in your program text - they don't represent a different type of object.

Comment: @holdenweb Thanks for explaining that for jtaylor. If `u` had been used instead of `r` before Python 3, then the data type would different. After Python 3, substituting a `b` for a `r` also changes the data type.

Answer (score 1):

Look like GitPython can't find git.exe.

Try setting the environment variable **GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE**.
It's should most likely be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" if using *Git for Windows* with defaults

at command line (cmd.exe)

```
set GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions, but implementing them did not actually solve my problem. I did develop a work-around with the following code:

```
def statusChecker(repo, lastCommit):
    uncommittedFiles = []
    files = os.listdir(repo)
    for file in files:
        if os.path.getmtime(repo + "\\\\" + file) > lastCommit:
            uncommittedFiles.append(file)
    uncommittedFiles = uncommittedFiles.remove(".git")
    return uncommittedFiles
```

As long as you use something like `lastCommit = repo.head.commit.committed_date` for the `lastCommit` argument this should work well.

Comment: This is not a stable solution to the problem.